# How to fix trailing garbage bug in HighCharts R?

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

I recently stumble across a problem using highcharts in R.
When simply plotting a map of french departments :

```
hcmap("countries/fr/fr-all-all")
```

I see the following error in the prompt

```
Content type 'text/javascript' length 128539 bytes (125 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 125 KB

Error: parse error: trailing garbage
          [[3530,136],[3530,-689]]]}}]};
                     (right here) ------^
```

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work :

```
remotes::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")
library(highcharter) 
hcmap(map ="custom/world-highres2.js")
```

I'm not really advanced in JavaScript so I can really dive into low-level details.
Furthermore, this error is new, it used to work about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: I recently stumbleD*
I can 'T really dive into low-level details*

Comment: This is likely related to this already reported problem:
Https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/741

If this solution does not solve your problem, please contact the author of this wrapper for more detailed help.